# When is it that $\int f d(g+h) \neq \int f dg + \int f dh$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Let $g,h:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be of bounded variation.

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable along $g$ and $h$.

> ** Problem1**
>
> When is it that $\int_a^b fd(g+h) \neq \int_a^b fdg + \int_a^b fdh$?

(Nevertheless, I have proven that if $f$ is continuous, the equality holds.)

Define $g_1(x)=1/2(V_a^x(g) + g(x))$ and $g_2(x)=1/2(V_a^x(g) - g(x))$.
Then $g=g_1-g_2$ and let's call this the canonical decomposition of $g$.

(Note that it is the **definition** to say "$f$ is integrable along $g$ iff $f$ is integrable along $g_1$ and $g_2$".)

Let $h_1,h_2,(g+h)_1,(g+h)_2$ be the canonical decomposition of $h,g+h$.

> **Problem2**
>
> Since $V_a^x(g+h)\leq V_a^x (g)+V_a^x(h)$, even though $f$ is integrable along $g,h$, it does not gurantee that $f$ is integrable along $g+h$. When is $f$ integrable along $g+h$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the result and notations I answered in: [Necessary and sufficient condition for Integrability along bounded variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432730/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-integrability-along-bounded-variation/1432737#1432737)

It is sufficient to prove that $f$ is integrable along the total variation of $g+h$.

Since $U(P,f,V_a^x (g+h)) - L( P,f,V_a^x (g+h)) = \sum (M_i -m_i ) V_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} (g+h) \leq \sum (M_i - m_i ) (V_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} (g) + V_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} (h))$, $f$ is integrable along $g+h$.